# Setting and getting Time

Tags: c++

I have a cybercafe and I am installing windows xp on the clients machines; to make it easy to secure clients computers against changes to system I am installing Deep Freeze program so as you know this program dreezes the partition it is set to when it is enabled. I am freezing the local drive C of clients but sometimes maybe due to CMOS battery is dead I have to set time each time I start the PCs so when I try to modify time -as you can guess- I got the message "you don't have the proper privilege level to change the System Time" I tried to build a small application to force setting the time so I used SYSTEMTIME st;
st.wHour=03; for example then SetLocalTime(&st); but this functions fails..
so is there a good coding stuff to get rid of this annoying problem??
thnak you in advance

Comment: Why bother? NTP would be your friend

Comment: Read up on NTP. Will keep you PCs clock in sync

Comment: but bro is it impossible to set time manullay??

Comment: Of course through the control panel.

Comment: please would you show me how?

Comment: Windows XP will be completely unsupported by Microsoft in six months. Why are you using it for a new deployment?